# Detect if css style changed

Tags: jquery

How can I detect if div changed `display` style between `none` & `block` in any time (not on click, mouseover etc.)?

I tried

```
if ($('#div').css('display') == 'block') {
    $("#div2").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
}
```

which checks only once, but if `display` is changed after 10 seconds after nothing happens.

Comment: Set time interval to check changes. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Is something causing it to change other than your own code?

Comment: other jQuery changes 'display', that is a slideshow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ay5DQ/)

```
function change() {
    if ($('#div').css('display') == 'block') {
        $("#div2").css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $("#div2").css('display', 'block');
    }
    setTimeout(change, 1000);
}
setTimeout(change, 1000);
$('#change').click(function () {
    $("#div").toggle(function(){$("#div1").css('display', 'inline')});
});
```

This will check your `if` query every 1 second (1000ms).

Answer (score 0):

You may try `window.setInterval()`.

This might help: [SelfHTML reference to setInterval](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/window.htm#set_interval)

Answer (score 0):

Also it might be worth noting there's a more jquery-like aproach to doing this:

```
if (!$('#div1').is(':hidden')) {
    $('#div2').hide();
}
```