# Checking for style, then inserting element once with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to edit a popup generated by a plugin, so I have limited access to the HTML file to be able to do this. Therefore I'm trying with jQuery.

Basically, once the PopUp's styling changes to appear, I want to add text into the popup itself. The way I have it set up at the moment is this, based on an answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635259/detect-if-css-style-changed).

```
function change() {
    if ($('.bold_lightbox').css('display') == 'block') {
        console.log('lightbox is shown');
        $('<p>Pricing Information Goes Here</p>').insertAfter('.bold_option_set');
    } else {
        console.log('lightbox is not visible');
    }
    setTimeout(change, 1000);
}
setTimeout(change, 1000);
```

This works, and successfully adds text into the popup. However, it continues to check every second, which in turn duplicates the paragraph over and over again until the popup is closed.

I'd like to be able to stop adding in the paragraph once it has been added in once.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a flag to check if the text has already been added, like so:

```
var done=false;
function change() {
    if ($('.bold_lightbox').css('display') == 'block') {
        console.log('lightbox is shown');
        $('<p>Pricing Information Goes Here</p>').insertAfter('.bold_option_set');
        done = true;
    } else {
        console.log('lightbox is not visible');
    }
    if(!done)
        setTimeout(change, 1000);
}
setTimeout(change, 1000);
```

HIH

Comment: That's great, it's worked for me. One question though, is there a way to tweak it so that re-opening the popup begins the process again?

Comment: @SamJohnson surely the popup has something like an *onclose* or *ondestroy* event. it may depend on where you are declaring this function, but you could declare `var done = false;` somewhere you can use it here AND inside the handler of the event where you can reset it to false, this way next time the popup shows again, the variable will be ready, got it?

Comment: Afraid I'm not quite sure what you mean. Maybe my use of 'popup' was incorrect. It's basically a div that appears and hides with CSS.

Comment: @SamJohnson try to include all relevant info/code when posting your question. well, if it's just a div you are creating and manipulating, it should be even easier since you have total control over it, now all you have to do is `done = false;` INSIDE where/when ever you are hiding your div, try it

Comment: Sorry, I definitely haven't been clear. So the PopUp div doesn't actually exist until a button is clicked to show it. This is all done through a third party Shopify Plugin, so I don't actually have access to the code that does this. Therefore, I don't think I could add `done = false; ` within it.

Comment: look, it does not matter, as long as YOU are the one hiding it (via a close button, maybe?) what ever code you are executing to hide the popup, just include `done=false;` there and that's it. Please don't tell me it hides on its own with a beautiful fade out :).

Comment: @SamJohnson, in case you didn't see the comment, forgot to add @

Comment: thanks for your help. Still having a bit of trouble I'm afraid. I've found this code (image) which appears to be where the element is hidden and shown. However adding in the done=false in the hide element function doesn't appear to solve it.